# Big X in Usernames?

Tags: bug, design

In the font used for usernames, the X is oddly distinctly larger than the other letters (see: my username on answers here and on the main site). Not just a little, like it seems like a half-capital compared to the rest.

Comment: which browser/windows version?

Comment: it looks fine me to me... what browser/ver/os?

Comment: Firefox 11 but not IE8 on Windows XP.

Comment: It tricked C. Ross: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2161

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 7 x64 with chrome.  But NOT IE8 - the x is normal sized in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same effect (both with Chrome/Windows 7 and IE9/Windows 7).

It's very weird.  the over-sized *x* appears only on HTML elements using the [Lusitana Regular](http://www.ffonts.net/Lusitana.font) font. However, small caps letters of said font seem to be all in line with one another.

If your computer/browser doesn't have said font installed (mine doesn't), the CSS instructs the browser to use the [Palatino Linotype](http://www.whatfontis.com/Palatino-Linotype.font) which, again, has a "regular" small caps *x*.

I didn't experimented further; but if I have to bet on something, I'd say that the Lusitana font stored on the stackexchange server is not the regular version.